# How to manage information from articles?

Tags: cms

I collect articles from the web with various useful information that could be interesting to me and my colleagues. I'd like to store them (offline) and offer access by a web interface. Additional useful features would be to store meta-information like title, date, etc. and full-text search. Possibly, additional features like tag clouds of document groups...

What would be the best way to achieve this? I've tried googling "information management" and "content management", but I haven't had success finding anything appropriate.

Any advice how to search for a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use [OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/), copy-paste of articles , will usually preserve the formatting, and it also adds a helpful link to the original website should you want to visit the source again. 
It also had a useful screenshot tool that sends the image straight to OneNote.
It's free and it works with other MS Office tools.
If you create a [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/) account your onenote syncs with the cloud, allowing you to access it from any machine , and also share it with other people. 
This is the screenshot of my Onenote where I copy pasted your question into it

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "It's free" Doesn't that assume that the OP has already purchased a license for MS Office, as well as likey MS Windows? What's to say the OP runs Windows at all?

Comment: Its completely free, you don't need an Office license for it. And since it runs on windows, mac, android, and iOS ; it covers a lot of platforms.

Comment: I normally do not upvote a product recomendation.  I decided to do so because the answer placed the author's own question into OneNote which was a nice touch.